# Signing out External Cookies before Signing in ApplicationCookie - OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, katana, asp.net-identity-2

I am currently studying the new ASPNET Identity and Owin Authentication so that I can customize it for my own use. I just created a default MVC 5 Application and came across this piece of code

```
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie); /// WHY??
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

**The Question**

Is there any security risk to leaving an External Cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the purpose of that line is to Deactivate the External Cookie that was gotten from the 3rd Party Provider. Since The intention is to transfer the Identity of the user from the 3rd Party to the Local Identity.

Not doing so would cause the cookie to remain valid even after the user has signed out.

Comment: I know it's been two years, but why not remove it on log out? Is there a security risk with that